# simple SAT question. confused.

Tags: education

[image: sat question]

My friend selected option B, I did C. We're confused. Can someone please explain this for my friend?

Comment: Your friend has not got a perfect score me thinks..

Answer (score 1):

No doubt Option $\,\,\,\,C\,\,\,\,\,$

Note that $a^{m+n}=a^m \cdot a^n$

Observe that
\begin{align}
(2x)^{3y}-(2x)^{y} \\= (2x)^{y+2y}-(2x)^{y}\\=(2x)^{y}[(2x)^{2y}-1]
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Option C is correct obviously because we can see that
                    \begin{align}
             (2x)^{3y}-(2x)^{y} \\= (2x)^{y+2y}-(2x)^{y}\\=(2x)^{y}[(2x)^{2y}-1]
\end{align}
Option B is wrong because if we take out $\ 2^y $ common then we will get 
$\ 2^y{[2^{2y} . x^{3y}-x^y}]$